# How to use tshark to do this task

Tags: networking

I don't have any base knowledge about tshark, and it is hard to find any tutorial to help me with this.

So now I have a pcap file which consists a lot of network flows; a time range; an ip addr; a tcp port number; the number of packets sent by the ip addr OR the number of packets received by the ip addr.

What I want to do is that first I let tshark to read from that pcap file, and then use the time range to filter out all the network flows that are in that time range, and then use the ip addr to filter out all the network flows from that ip addr on that already-filter-out-by-time flows, and then use the tcp port number and the number of packets sent/received by the ip addr to finally locate the flow I want. Then follow this flow/stream and save the whole conversation to a new pcap file.

Anyone can help? I'll be very very appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using tshark instead of wireshark?  This sort of stuff is a lot easier to do with the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-r` flag to specify the input file, `-R` to specify the filters and then `-w` to write the dissected traffic to the output file.

You can get some information over here [TShark capture and filter examples](http://www.codealias.info/technotes/the_tshark_capture_and_filter_example_page)

The wireshark-filters manual page  has more information about them.